# Default username/password for CentOS 7 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: password, user, login

What is the default username and password for CentOS 7 for Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Posting this question as I couldn't find the answer online and had to spam passwords in until I got it right

Answer (score 15):

Defaults are

**Username**: root
**Password**: centos

Comment: spamming random passwords wasn't the most elaborate way to find out but it worked! Also when someone googles this it comes up pretty high in the search engine so I hope I've saved some people time in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

> and had to spam passwords in until I got it right

the user name and password is mentioned in the official website

> root password : centos

https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/AltArch/armhfp

if it changes in the future, the change will be in the official website.

Comment: It was not mentioned on the site in 2016 which is clearly why this post has so many upvotes. Lol as if you down voted me for that. Well done 

Comment: i just tried to install this distro this month, i had no idea the password was not there in 2016 ... thanks.